# Which database is recommended to use with Ruby on Rails? (Considering hosting offers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

I'm a rails novice, so i'm wondering what is the best choice about the database to use? As i've been reading PostgreSQL is widely used and SQLite too. But what about MySQL? It have good hosting options with this schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostgreSQL is my first choice on any project needing a database. As many people(including myself) will tell you, Postgres is far and away the best choice. For most people the advanced features of any RDBMS, are not really needed when first starting with Rails since ActiveRecord will handle all of your DB interactions. MySQL will also work but overall it's lacking many of the features PostgreSQL has introduced in recent years, and when you start working with the RDBMS some of the features like streaming replication will be things you want. [Also here was a recent post highlighting some of Postgres' advantages.](http://wekeroad.com/2012/07/19/postgresql-rising)

SQLite is only really used in development and is intended to be used as an embedded DB, and subsequently has certain limitations that make it unsuitable in production. I would use this when first starting out with Rails so you don't have to deal with all the database configuration options, and can instead focus on working with Rails. At any point in development you can set up Postgres or MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @jroesch very helpful article. I really didn't know many of those facts about PostgreSQL.

Comment: The submitted link expects username and password to be entered. Not even googling helped.

Answer (score 4):

Make your choice:

## SQLite

When To Use SQLite

- **Embedded applications**
- **Disk access replacement**
- **Testing**

When Not To Use SQLite

- Multi-user applications
- Applications requiring high write volumes

## MySQL

When To Use MySQL

- **Distributed operations**
- **High security**
- **Web-sites and web-applications**
- **Custom solutions**

When Not To Use MySQL

- SQL compliance
- Concurrency
- Lack of features

## PostgreSQL

When To Use PostgreSQL

- **Data integrity**
- **Complex, custom procedures**
- **Integration**
- **Complex designs**

When Not To Use PostgreSQL

- Speed
- Simple set ups
- Replication

Taken from this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems

Answer (score 3):

You're free to use any database you want. SQLite is for local site and PostgreSQL is very populare but I think it's just a choice. If you want to use MySQL, it isn't a problem. There is no advantage in benchmarks. It's like Django or Rails, just a religion...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say there is a "best choice" for a database to use with Rails. The best choice will depend on the individual project. As others have stated SQLite is generally better for development. Since you're just starting out, I think the most important choice of a database is that it's popular. Both MySQL and PostgreSQL are popular and you should easily be able to find tutorials and stackoverflow answers to issues you run into. Some of the Rails specific hosts (like EngineYard) have been making PostgreSQL their default DB. If your using AWS, the gem Rubber makes deploying with either MySQL or PostgreSQL very easy.

Once you start to get comfortable with MySQL or PostgreSQL, I would recommend playing around with a NoSQL database like MongoDB.